# Setup value for half of records (Oracle, PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql, oracle12c

I'm trying to loop all my records from tableA and for half of records set-up for columnA = 1 and for second half of records columnA = 2.

```
declare

Type T2 Is Table Of TableA%Rowtype Index By Binary_Integer;
V2 T2;
Type T3 Is Table Of TableA%Rowtype Index By Binary_Integer;
V3 T3;

Maxrow Number(10);
mHalf  Number(10);
begin

 Select round(Max(Rownum)/2) Into Maxrow From TableA;

 Select * Bulk Collect Into V2 From TableA Where Rownum < Mhalf;
 Select * Bulk Collect Into V3 From TableA Where Rownum >= Mhalf;

 For I In 1..2 Loop
   If I=1 Then          
      For Z In V2.First..V2.Last Loop
         update tableA set columnA = 1 where Rownum = V2(Z);
      End Loop;
   Elsif I=2 Then
      For ZZ In V3.First..V3.Last Loop
         update tableA set columnA = 2 where Rownum = V3(ZZ);
      End Loop;
   End if;       

 End Loop;    
end;
```

But something is getting wrong. When I'm checking:

```
Select Count(*) From tableA Where Rownum > 300;
```

here I don't get any records

Comment: `Where Rownum > 300;` will never return any rows. [quote from the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ROWNUM-Pseudocolumn.html#GUID-2E40EC12-3FCF-4A4F-B5F2-6BC669021726): "*Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer are always false*"

Comment: yes, the code from @Ted at ORCL.Pro is fine

Comment: But PL/SQL is a complete overkill here. This can be done with one simply UPDATE statement

Comment: please show how to perform the update then, thanks!

Comment: `update table_a set column_a = mod(rownum, 2) + 1`

Comment: thanks, when I need set different value then I better to use plsql code block

Comment: If you need a more complicated expression use `CASE`. Iterating over rows and doing single row updates with a cursor loop is almost always a bad choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare 
  mHalf  Number; 
  l_rec TableA%rowtype; 
  cntr NUMBER := 1; 
  CURSOR cur IS Select * From TableA FOR UPDATE OF columnA; 
begin 

 Select round(count(*)/2,0) Into mHalf From TableA; 

OPEN cur; 
  LOOP 
    FETCH cur INTO l_rec; 
        EXIT WHEN cur%notfound; 
    UPDATE 
      tableA 
    SET 
      columnA=CASE WHEN cntr <= mhalf then 1 else 2 end 
    WHERE 
      CURRENT OF cur; 
    cntr := cntr +1;       
  END LOOP; 

  Commit; 

end;
```

Comment: for V2 I have "<", for V3 I need to ">"

Comment: you can order by rownum desc ;)

Comment: Select Rownum, L.* From tableA L Where Rownum < 300 
order by rownum desc;----not working

Comment: hmmm, I am preparing a solution with cursor

Comment: something is wrong: PLS-00394: wrong number of values in the INTO list of a FETCH statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187931/discussion-between-ted-at-orcl-pro-and-4est).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * Bulk Collect Into V2 From TableA Where Rownum < Mhalf;
 Select * Bulk Collect Into V3 From TableA Where Rownum >= Mhalf;
```

Change to:

```
SELECT  * 
BULK COLLECT INTO V2
FROM    (
         SELECT a.*,
                ROWNUM rn 
         FROM   (
                  SELECT  *
                  FROM    tablea
                ) a
        )
WHERE   rn < Mhalf;

SELECT  * 
BULK COLLECT INTO V#
FROM    (
         SELECT a.*,
                ROWNUM rn 
         FROM   (
                  SELECT  *
                  FROM    tablea
                ) a
        )
WHERE   rn >= Mhalf;
```

Comment: I tried but dont working.....SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*, ROWNUM rn FROM tableA a ) WHERE rn < 2; is FINE

Comment: Answer Updated, try now.

Comment: sorry but it did not work, anway thx for help, already @Ted at ORCL.Pro is working great